# Xcode Developer Documentation Link Hover Jumps To Top

Tags: xcode, browser, hover

I don't know how I got into this state, but the Xcode documentation window has been exhibiting this strange behavior of "jumping to top" whenever I hover over a link in one of the doc files.

For example, I'll be scrolling down to, say, the methods of a Class Reference, and as soon as I hover over one of them, the doc window jumps right back to the top.

Has anyone else encountered this? If so, is there a fix for within Xcode?

Meanwhile, opening up the doc in a browser works around the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the replies everyone!

Meanwhile, I have just stumbled upon a workaround.

To preface, I have to clarify/correct two things for my particular case:

1. The problem only occurs when hovering over the links in the Tasks section.
2. The jump doesn't necessarily go to the top-of-page. Rather, it goes to wherever the original landing spot was when you opened the doc. (In URL parlance this is the fragment, e.g. *#//apple_ref...*).

On to the workaround:

In the Xcode doc viewer (and even in Safari), there should be a "Jump To..." drop-down in the "developer-documentation" window located to the right (and as a peer) of the "table of contents" expander when this problem occurs. You only need click on it once, dismiss it, and then the jumping problem goes away!

Comment: ThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyouThankyou. I hate XCode. I hate it so much. This is the cherry on the cake. But I'm glad you found a workaround.

Comment: Hehe. Glad it was useful! :)

Incidentally, Xcode 3.2 is soooper. Among other things, it was the receipient of a serious overhaul in how documentation is handled ... and I'm liking it a LOT more!

Comment: As per cporter71, the drop-down is in the "developer-documentation" window located to the right (and as a peer) of the "table of contents" expander.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered it (only when viewing the docs in Safari, not the doc viewer itself), and I believe it's a known bug fixed in Xcode 3.2 (for Snow Leopard).

Comment: Happens to me in Snow Leopard 10A432 in the doc viewer.

Comment: Boo hiss! I would love to find the root cause and nip it in the bud. We'll see ...